# Chai Test Complex object

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to use [Chai Things](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-things) to test a REST response as well as testing the right Objects are being returned. The Object contains an array and this is where I'm running into issues.

Example:

```
{ 
  data:[
    {
     bookTitle:"Lord of the Rings",
     author: "J.R.R. Tolkien",
     tags: ["fiction", "fantasy", "classic"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried variations of the following:

`res.body.data.should.contain.a.thing.with.property('tags',  ["fiction", "fantasy", "classic"]`);

But I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught AssertionError: expected an element of [ Array(1) ] to have a property 'tags' of ["fiction", "fantasy", "classic"], but got ["fiction", "fantasy", "classic"]
```

Comment: Try `should.all.contain`. https://github.com/chaijs/chai-things#all

Comment: This does not work: `res.body.data.should.all.contain.a.thing.with.property('tags',  ["fiction", "fantasy", "classic"]);`

Answer (score 1):

So in looking at this I guess I my approach was wrong. I assert that body contains an array of objects. Then access that object and verify that way. I also had the wrong understanding of `.property()`, the returned value was an object, not the values of the property.